# Unable to install Intel HAXM - What are the implications?

Tags: android-studio

I am just beginning with Android, and installed Android studio on windows 10. At the final stage of installation I got the error

```
Unable to install Intel HAXM
Your CPU does not support VT-x.
Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
Here are some of your options:
 1) Use a physical device for testing
 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
 (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)
```

I am not understanding this. Seems to be a hardware limitation, but I want to know how this will effect my development of android. Can someone please nudge me to right location?

[image]

Comment: your virtual android device will be slower than it might be otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @EvilTeach says, intel HAXM is only for Android Emulation which make it faster than without it. If you rely on Android Virtual Device (AVD), then you should enable it. Afaik, you need to enable **VT-x** from you computer **bios**. If you developing with the real device, without using AVD at all, you can safely ignore it.

Here an excerpt from [official Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager):

> Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) is a
>   hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor) that uses Intel®
>   Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT) to speed up Android* app
>   emulation on a host machine. In combination with [Android x86 emulator
>   images](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-4-4-kitkat-x86-emulator-system-image) provided by Intel and the [official Android SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), Intel
>   HAXM allows for faster Android emulation on Intel VT enabled systems.

For installation of HAXM, you can visit [Installation Instructions for Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) - Microsoft Windows*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

Answer (score 0):

To install the HAXM driver, follow these steps:

1. Open the SDK Manager.
2. Click the SDK Update Sites tab and then select Intel HAXM.
3. Click OK.
4. After the download finishes, run the installer.

   For example, it might be in this location:

   ```
    sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe.
   ```
5. Use the wizard to complete the installation.
6. After installing HAXM, confirm that the virtualization driver is operating correctly by entering the following command in a Command Prompt window:

   ```
    sc query intelhaxm
   ```

I hope you successfully install....

[check my website](https://basicandroidprogram.blogspot.com/)